# How to change html text with javascript based on text inside currently clicked div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

First time posting a question. I think I should mention that I am a beginner in javascript/jquery.

I have a gallery which shows details about the image on hover (in form of text). And when clicked it executes a javascript that popups an *iframe* and changes the *src* attribute to the clicked div element's *href*.

Now that works well but is not quiet mobile friendly because there is no hover on a touchscreen device. So mobile visitors are not able to see the details about the images.

I am not so familiar with javascript I just find scripts on forums (basically here), change it a bit, merge more scripts to achieve what I want.
Therefore **I do not know how I could change text with that script that would replace a "LOADING..." text under the *iframe* element to the description of what div I have clicked.** It just complicates things that the text I need to change TO is not in the parent div the script checks to replace the *src*, but in the child div *classed* "description".

Here is the "source" html:

```html
<div class="work categ1 categ2" href="https://youtube.com/embed/example">
  <img class="ref" src="/portfolio/example1.png">
  <div class="description">EXAMPLE1 </br> (2016) </div>
</div>
<div class="work categ3" href="http://webpage-example">
  <img class="ref" src="/portfolio/example2.png">
  <div class="description">EXAMPLE2 </br> (2014) </div>
</div>
<div class="work categ3" href="https://youtube.com/embed/example2">
  <img class="ref" src="/portfolio/example3.png">
  <div class="description">EXAMPLE3 </br> (2013) </div>
</div>
```

This is the html of the popup iframe:

```html
<div class="popup">
  <iframe class="popupVid" width="560" min-height="300px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/" title="Embed video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <img src="/img/x.png" style="height:45px">
  <p class="description">LOADING...</p>
</div>
```

And here's the current javascript:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".popup").hide();
    $(".work").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".popup").show();
        $("iframe").eq(0).attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
    })
      $(".popup").on("click", function(e) {
        $(".popup").hide();
        $("iframe").eq(0).attr("src", "");
      })
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.key === "Escape") { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
          $(".popup").hide();
          $("iframe").eq(0).attr("src", "");
        }
      });
  </script>
```

To help understand the script a bit more the "popup" *classed* div fills the whole window with a half transparent black color. So when you click outside of the *iframe* it will close the *iframe*.

I hope I shared everything that is needed. I hope someone can help me out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like $('.description').html('description details here');

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have found this code but it just changed the mentioned part to a text that's determined in the javascript so this code does not pick the description from the clicked div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>

<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="work categ1 categ2" href="https://youtube.com/embed/example"><img class="ref" src="/portfolio/example1.png"><div class="description">EXAMPLE1 </br> (2016)</div></div>
      <div class="work categ3" href="http://webpage-example"><img class="ref" src="/portfolio/example2.png"><div class="description">EXAMPLE2 </br> (2014)</div></div>
      <div class="work categ3" href="https://youtube.com/embed/example2"><img class="ref" src="/portfolio/example3.png"><div class="description">EXAMPLE3 </br> (2013)</div></div>


<div class="popup">
  <iframe class="popupVid" width="560" min-height="300px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/" title="Embed video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <img src="/img/x.png" style="height: 45px;">
  <p class="description_popup">LOADING...</p>
  </div>

</body>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".popup").hide();
    $(".work").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".popup").show();
        $("iframe").eq(0).attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
        var desc = $(this).find('.description').text();
        //console.log(desc);
        $(".description_popup").text(desc);

    })
      $(".popup").on("click", function(e) {
        $(".popup").hide();
        $("iframe").eq(0).attr("src", "");
        var desc = $(this).find('.description').text();
        //console.log(desc);
        $(".description_popup").text(desc);
      })
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.key === "Escape") { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
          $(".popup").hide();
          $("iframe").eq(0).attr("src", "");
          var desc = $(this).find('.description').text();
        //console.log(desc);
        $(".description_popup").text(desc);
        }
      });
  
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! It really did the job!

These two single lines made the job:
`var desc = $(this).find('.description').text();
$(".description_popup").text(desc);`

What I have discovered that it even works if I only add it to the first part of the script. Was there a reason why it was needed to add it to the popup closing parts of the script?

Comment: Welcome davidw.

Answer (score 1):

Just for those who look for the fast answer, Nazeer's code solved the problem.

What he added were these lines in the javascript:

```
var desc = $(this).find('.description').text();
$(".description_popup").text(desc);
```

And he changed the LOADING text's *class* to something different:

```
<p class="description_popup">LOADING...</p>
```

And that's it! It is how you change the text under the popup to the currently clicked div's text.
Thank you Nazeer!